# Svchost.exe high CPU usage - EC2 - Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running Windows Server 2008 r2 on AWS. Today I see that svchost.exe takes 100 % cpu. I have right click on svchost.exe and choose go to process in Taskmanager. but there is no process high lighted.

I see that "Beyond Compare" as a description for svchost.exe. Please refer the below screenshots and help me to fix the issue.
[Task Manager[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHaSo.png)

Comment: Svchost is not the problem. The problem is in the service which is using svchost.exe and can be many... https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: I understand that svchost is not the problem. The problem is I couldn't find the services which are using that particular svchost process which consumes 100% cpu. I tried right click Svchost.exe-->Go To Process in Task Manager, Its doesn't high lighted any services.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Svchost.exe file location and it was C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\National. I could able remove the exe file but it generates automatically. I suspect that it might be some virus, I have used McAfee for scanning the folder C:\ProgramData. But it does not detects anything.

I have checked the startup applications in "msconfig" and I couldn't find any thing different. But I can see that the service National Instruments Domain Service is running in services tab (hiding all Microsoft services). I Google it and I couldn't find any problem with that service. But I could see that the exe file name is differ from what I have it on my server for National Instruments Domain Service. The location and file name for National Instruments Domain Service in my server is C:\ProgramData\National\taskngr.exe.

I Google it and came to know that taskngr.exe might be a virus. So I stopped and disabled National Instruments Domain Service ( file location C:\ProgramData\National\taskngr.exe) after that I can able to kill the Svchost.exe process permanently and CPU usage came normal.

I have removed two folders C:\ProgramData\National and C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\National permanently from the server. Also I have uninstalled the National Instruments Domain Service ( Service name is National).

And one more thing I noticed that in Task Manager, All other svchost process are running as svchost.exe ("s" small) in my case it was Svchost.exe ("S" caps).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update you Windows 2008 Server to latest